# matlab class - method allows user choosing which property to be modified

Tags: matlab, class

i want to build a class like that:

```
classdef myclass < handle
  properties
    v1 = struct('value', 100)
    v2 = struct('value', 200);
  end
  methods
    function plusone(obj, vars)      % SHOULD BE MODIFIED SOMEHOW??
      vars.value = vars.value + 1;
    end
  end
end
```

And my question is, how should i write the method `plusone` so in Command Window i can **choose which property i want to modify**, i.e. i choose to modify property `v2`:

```
a = myclass();
a.plusone(a.v2);
```

that update the field `value` of variable `v2` of object `a` ? Or is there a problem with my thinking method?

Comment: Please add the `Matlab` tag, it will give you question more attention and probably better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a method like that, though you need to pass the reference to the field differently:

```
methods
    function plusone(obj, propName)      
      obj.(propName).value = obj.(propName).value + 1;
    end
end
```

To call the method, pass the reference as string:

```
a = myclass();
a.plusone('v2')
```

Comment: thanks, that's what i was looking for. But what is the difference between `.(propName)` and `.propName` ? I tried with normal function to display (propName) and propName, both are char array ...?

Comment: @scmg: `.(propName)` allows you to pass a char array that contains the name of the property. This allows you to dynamically access that property. `.propName` will look for a property called `propName`, while `.(propName)` will look for a property called whatever the value of `propName` is. It also works with structures, by the way.